# VBA referencing next cell in For loop

Tags: vba

I need to compare a cell to the one below it in a loop. i know for most languages you can say something like "if cells(i,1).value = cells(i+1,1).value then..."

is there a way to do this in vba for some reason it isn't working for me. thanks

```
For i = 7 To ltrw 
    If (Cells(i, 1).Value = 0 And Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 0 Then 
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True 
    End If 
Next i
```

Comment: That should work, assuming i > 0 - What happens to make you think it does not work?

Comment: If it's not working then it's best to post the actual code you're trying, along with any error message you might be getting.

Comment: The code is pasted below.. basically i'm just trying to hide an entire row if the cell in that row, as well as the one below it contains a zero. I'm not getting error messages, just nothing is happening when i run it.
For i = 7 To ltrw
 If  (Cells(i, 1).Value = 0 And Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 0 Then
    
Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
  End If
      Next i

Comment: It's best to edit your question if you need to add code - it's too difficult to read if you put it in a comment.

Comment: What's the value of `ltrw` when it runs?

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
For i = 7 To ltrw 
    If Cells(i).Value = Cells(i + 1).Value Then  ' you can skip the ", 1" as its optional
        Cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True 
    End If 
Next i
```